# How to connect to Kubernetes via Gitlab Pipeline using the Terraform Kubernetes Provider

Tags: kubernetes, terraform, gitlab, gitlab-ci, cicd

We have connected some of our repositories in Gitlab to a Kubernetes cluster. There is an agent installed on our cluster that allows the connection. This is documented on Gitlab's web pages (e.g., [here](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/clusters/agent/)). The important thing is that all of this works fine when we are using `kubectl` in the CI/CD pipelines (in Gitlab).

Instead of using `kubectl`, we now want to deploy resources into this cluster via Terraform. The problem is that it doesn't work. We are using Terraform 1.5.3 and the Kubernetes Provider in version 2.23.0. The provider configuration is currently empty and looks like this:

```
provider "kubernetes" {
}
```

The error will print out `connection refused`.

From my understanding the provider should pick up the right context automatically, like `kubectl` does.

Anyone has had a similar situation and can help us out? Even an example would be much appreciated, since I was not able to find any examples that implemented this approach anywhere online. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Same here. I am just learning Gitlab ci/cd. I have a minikube cluster. From the pipeline I can see the cluster with kubectl (after a bit of tweaking), I can do a terraform init, terraform validate but cannot do a terraform plan because it cannot find context

Answer (score 0):

you have to use the kubeconfig and context to be able to use it from the pipeline. This way:

```
provider "kubernetes" {
   alias = "groot" { alias = "groot" { config_path = 
   "/builds/ccsolutions.io/
   config_path = "/path/to/your/repository.tmp/KUBECONFIG"
   config_context = your/kube/context/repo/and/agent:name
}
```

To find the path easier you can run an env in your pipeline.